# Using blpapi and xbbg to pull member holdings and weight data from Bloomberg?

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

Beginner Python user here. I was wondering if anyone has had any success using blpapi and xbbg to pull member holdings and constituent weight data directly into Python from Bloomberg (e.g. from a portfolio or ETF or index). I have a BBG license, of course.

Thank you in advance to any suggestions! Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps give an example of a ETF or index that you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

To add on to what  ytoledano said you can do the below to get index constituents:

```
from xbbg import blp
index = "SPCPGN Index"
index_constituents = blp.bds(index,"INDX_MWEIGHT")
print(index_constituents)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how you get it in Excel:

```
=BDS("SPX Index","INDX_MWEIGHT")
```

The python equivalent should work